# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'main'

Tags: python, c#, visual-studio, ironpython

[Error Message after Pip Install](https://i.stack.imgur.com/acGIx.png)

[Error Message after running the application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ZGp9.png)

I am trying to run a python script through Visual Studio(C#) using IronPython, but when I try to install packages such as 'Random' and 'Prettytable' which I have used in my python script in Visual Studio under Python Environments, I get the following error:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'main'`

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: so, just to be clear, you're getting an `AttributeError` when `pip install`ing?

Comment: Yes, basically under Python Environment, I have Python 3.7 and IronPython 2.7. This issue arises when I try installing packages under IronPython, under Python the packages are installing just fine.

Comment: can you give us steps to reproduce what you're seeing? basically start from scratch and document how you get to the error, so that we can see if it's a problem with just your computer

Comment: I have attached an image as 'Error Message' in my post, can you please refer to that ?

Comment: the picture you uploaded has nothing to do with `pip install`???

Comment: Basically I have built a desktop application, at the backend I am using SQLite database and right now I am running the python script manually through an IDE(PyCharm) which populates the database but I want it to be done through the application. But the desktop application is not running the python script and producing the error I have mentioned in the post.

Comment: I have added an image showing the error message after pip install, kindly refer to that.